# Why is my program being interferred by comments?

Tags: python, syntax-error, user-input, sys, unicode-escapes

Our tasks at school is to add a test example of the program at the bottom of the code with:

```
#example

"""

<insert example of you running the code>

"""
```

but when I do so, I get error. I never get it on any other codes, only on this one?:

```
C:\Users\David>C:\Users\David\Desktop\IN1900\uke38\qerror.py 1
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\IN1900\uke38\qerror.py", line 22
    """
    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 24-25: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

C:\Users\David>
```

My code is as following:

```
from math import sqrt
import sys

a=float(sys.argv[1])
b=float(sys.argv[2])
c=float(sys.argv[3])
d=(b**2)-(4*a*c)
x1=((-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a))
x2=((-b-sqrt(d))/(2*a))

print(f'The quadratic formula with used values gives two roots {x1:.1f} and {x2:.1f}')

#example
"""
#Fra command prompt:
#C:\Users\David>C:\Users\David\Desktop\IN1900\uke38\quadratic_roots_cml.py 1 0 -1
#The quadratic formula with used values gives two roots 1.0 and -1.0
#(koden funker ikke på et eller annet magisk vis når jeg bruker
"""
```

Comment: Triple-quoted strings are no comments, but multiline strings. In Python, comments start with `#`.

Answer (score 2):

Part of your string literal is being interpreted as an escaped unicode character. Such escape sequences start with `\U`. The easiest fix for this is to put an `r` in front of the opening triplet of double quotes.  This prevents any sort of escape processing of the text from happening:

```
r"""
#Fra command prompt:
#C:\Users\David>C:\Users\David\Desktop\IN1900\uke38\quadratic_roots_cml.py 1 0 -1
#The quadratic formula with used values gives two roots 1.0 and -1.0
#(koden funker ikke på et eller annet magisk vis når jeg bruker
"""
```

This is a lot easier than adding a bunch of extra slashes, and doesn't change the text's readability either.

Here's what the Python 3 docs say about "raw strings":

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a
> letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat
> backslashes as literal characters. As a result, in string literals,
> '\U' and '\u' escapes in raw strings are not treated specially. Given
> that Python 2.x’s raw unicode literals behave differently than Python
> 3.x’s the 'ur' syntax is not supported.

Comment: It turns off much of the escape processing for the string literal that follows.  See the following: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html - Note that the fact that it is a doc string has nothing to do with what's going on.  Putting `r` in front of any other string literal has the same effect.

Comment: I just realized that the link I supplied above is really old.  Here's where you can read about `r` in the Python 3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html - see above, where I added the relevant part of this page to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use double blackslashes on the line with the path, like that:

```
"""
"""
#Fra command prompt:
#C:\\Users\\David>C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\IN1900\\uke38\\quadratic_roots_cml.py 1 0 -1
#The quadratic formula with used values gives two roots 1.0 and -1.0
#(koden funker ikke på et eller annet magisk vis når jeg bruker
"""
"""
```

Comment: alternatively you can put `r` in front of the string to read it as a `raw` string, no special `\` characters

Answer (score 1):

The `\U` or `\u` in `\Users` and `\uke38` is being interpreted as a Unicode escape. Double the backslash.

```
#C:\\Users\David>C:\\Users\David\Desktop\IN1900\\uke38\quadratic_roots_cml.py 1 0 -1
```

Alternatively, note that you have comments in lines starting with `#`. So, the triple-quotes are not needed.

```
...
print(f'The quadratic formula with used values gives two roots {x1:.1f} and {x2:.1f}')

#example
#Fra command prompt:
#C:\Users\David>C:\Users\David\Desktop\IN1900\uke38\quadratic_roots_cml.py 1 0 -1
#The quadratic formula with used values gives two roots 1.0 and -1.0
#(koden funker ikke på et eller annet magisk vis når jeg bruker
```